# Win32 registry key writable by Everyone?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-vista, registry

Is there a Registry key which is allowed for write access to any users and is shared among them?

I need to store some machine-specific data in my application, but this piece of data must be machine-dependent, not logged-user-depended. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is only writable by Administrator. HKEY_CURRENT_USER is allowed for write, but is not shared with other users.

I think that in Windows filesystem folder C:\ProgramData (environment variable %ALLUSERSPROFILE%) is writable for anyone and is shared, but does Registry has something similar?

Answer (score 4):

It is the same for the file system as well as the registry, out of the box nothing is shared between users with a limited user account.  This is trivially solved by creating a directory or registry key that has write access by Everyone.  By an admin or a program that runs with admin rights.

Comment: Hans, are you sure? I have just tested "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data" folder (XP) and "C:\ProgramData" folder (Vista) on clean systems. Both allow write-access to them and share their files.

Comment: I'm sure about c:\programdata, the Users group only has read, list and exec rights on any machine I've ever seen.  It is however a persistent rumor that write access is sometimes granted.  Not sure what's up with that.  XP, hmm, different philosophy back then.  Try superuser.com for more support.

Comment: @Dmitry: Did you try writing to a file originally created by another user? I believe all users can write new files to the shared folders you mention and read files created there by other users, but cannot write to files created there by other users.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  There are only two persistent hives: HKLM and HKU.  As there are no shared hives under HKU you would have to store shared data somewhere under HKLM.  You can create your key and give it a security descriptor allowing Everyone full access.